# I cant see anything when my spinner is displayed or clicked

Tags: android, custom-controls, android-spinner

I have a custom spinner. I have made it as basic as possible to get it to work but im not seeing any values either in its initial value or its drop down, no response at all and no errors.

my custom xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:padding="5dip" />
```

my customAdapter class.

public class Game_AddFixtures_SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
private Context context;
private ArrayList<String>itemList;
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
public Game_AddFixtures_SpinnerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> itemList) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
    this.context=context;
    //this.itemList=itemList;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_custom, null);
    TextView v = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    Typeface myTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/gilsanslight.otf");
    v.setTypeface(myTypeFace);
    v.setText("shooobaloo");
    return convertView;
}


public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}

}
```

My Activity calling code

```
//TEST
Spinner spinner_fixture1= (Spinner)dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner_fixture1);
mySpinnerAdapter spinner= new mySpinnerAdapter(c,R.layout.spinner_custom,fixtureTeamList);
spinner_fixture1.setAdapter(spinner);
```

Comment: Any log? Try to put "false" instead of null in your convertView something like this inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_row, parent, false);

Comment: No luck. Just realised a typo, fixed - i had the wrong xml being inflated but still, that code doesnt get hit anyway...

Comment: No log as no errors afaics

Comment: Log doesn't mean "error"... you can Log your code to check if it actually gets there.

BTW.... why are you returning the TextView??? You must return convertView.

Comment: OOhhh that could be it - im not sure what and why im returning what i am

Comment: @MkiiSoft apologies, the log is massive and as i say nothing out of the ordninary - the getView and Get DropdownView do not get hit.

Comment: If you want to hit the dropdownview you must use: adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.your_layout_here); (this one goes just before the setAdapter)

Comment: Am i missing a @Override before getView? I added Override to the getView and removed the getDropDownView for now, no diff..... still cant get the getView() to be hit any ideas?

Comment: Yep, use the @Override before getView and getDropDownView. You can also make a getCustomView and set return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent); in your getView and getDropDownView

Comment: Does it have an override too?

Comment: getCustomView doesn't use @Override

Comment: Ok il try that but again - im not sure why that code would make a diff as i dont call it anywhere

Comment: Nope, i have updated the questioon for what i have now in my code. btw ur call was recursive so i changed it slightly, have a look. If you have any code i can copy then fw it as an answer

Comment: This is not the most hard example, but it should work just fine: http://androidexample.com/Custom_Spinner_With_Image_And_Text_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=84&aaid=107 Check how to adapter is formed. I've test that code and it works.